# Why alias not working for clear command deepIn linux?

Tags: linux, debian, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I have been using DeepIn 15.04 based on Debian 8, I installed oh-my-zsh, and created alias for 'clear' command like below:

```
alias clear='cls' # inside ~/.zshrc
```

Now, when I reload the zsh terminal and do 'cls' then I get error as "zsh: command not found: cls"

What is the reason behind this error and what can be the possible solution. Thank you.

Comment: `alias cls='clear'`?

Comment: This is a textbook example. Try to run the alias on the command line before placing it in the control file. The answer is in the prior comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) just google for the reason.

ii) Put below line in ~/.zshrc:

```
alias cls='clear'
```

and run

```
exec /usr/bin/zsh
```

cheers !!!